# Access Blocked: <project> has not completed the Google verification process

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I am building a simple script which polls some data and then updates a spreadsheet that I am giving to my client.  (It is a small project and I don't need anything fancy.)

So I created a Google Cloud project, enabled the Sheets API, and got a credential for a Desktop app.  When I try to run the [quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), I get an error:

**Access blocked: <my project name> has not completed the Google verification process**

I have tried googling and all the solutions seem to be oriented toward what a user should do if they see this, but I am the developer.   I only need to grant my own self access to this spreadsheet, since my script is the only thing that will be changing it (I will also share it with the client).

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried adding your account as a test user under the OAuth consent screen? You can use this link as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkZns_VOB6I

Comment: I'm glad it worked, let me compose it as an answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: pretty crazy that they release an incomplete documentation. Thanks for this

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to add the account as a test user under the OAuth consent screen:

1.) From the dashboard go to **APIs & Services** and click **OAuth concent screen**

[image]

2.) Under the **Test users**, click **+Add Users**. A menu will prompt on the right panel.
[image]

3.) Input the users email
[image]

4.) Reload the URL provided.

*Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkZns_VOB6I*

**Note: I am not affiliated with the video nor the owner of the youtube channel**

Comment: N.B.  in the end, using a service account ended up being a better move than a test user.

Comment: @luqui how can I set a service account instead of the test user?

Comment: @doplano don't remember .. these days I just ask ChatGPT about stuff like this, it usually puts me on the right track

Answer (score 6):

I agree @Twilight 's answer is ok, and when you want to allow other users to join, you have a button
[image: Status image from google console]

This is in Google Console -> API's and services -> Oauth consent screen, there is an option to publish app. And depending on your setup, you will need to provide a different amount of information.

For me privacy policy, terms of service, additional(optional) description of the app was required.