Mounting the drive in Google Colab Enterprise
!sudo echo -ne '\n' | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa >/dev/null 2>&1 # note: >/dev/null 2>&1 is used to supress printing
!sudo apt update >/dev/null 2>&1
!sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse >/dev/null 2>&1
!google-drive-ocamlfuse
!sudo apt-get install w3m >/dev/null 2>&1 # to act as web browser
!xdg-settings set default-web-browser w3m.desktop >/dev/null 2>&1 # to set default browser
%cd /content
!mkdir gdrive
%cd gdrive
!mkdir "My Drive"
!google-drive-ocamlfuse "/content/gdrive/My Drive"

I am getting the below error.
You should specify a client id (-id) and a client secret (-secret)

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Does it work in free Colab ? Colab Enterprise End User Credentials does not include Google Drive scope, do you know if its required for this integration to work? If so, I can provide a series of steps on how to do it.

From README.md
First, you must set up OAuth
2.0:

Activate the
Google Drive API.
Create an OAuth client ID.
Choose Desktop as Application type.
Set the Name to anything you like.

This way you will get a Client ID and Client secret that you can use to
access your Drive. To authorize google-drive-ocamlfuse, pass the client ID
and the client secret on the command line, e.g.:
google-drive-ocamlfuse -id xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com -secret XXX-YYY-ZZZ

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse?tab=readme-ov-file#usage

Thank you for your answer. After following the above steps. I receive a link to authenticate. After clicking on it . I get the below page . This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Need to try it, will get back to you.

There is one additional step which needs to be followed to make this work i.e. adding a test user to the app
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454425/access-blocked-project-has-not-completed-the-google-verification-process
After this it worked for me other wise it gives the error
Error: You should specify a client id (-id) and a client secret (-secret)


I tried with the following:
google-drive-ocamlfuse -debug -id XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com -secret YYYY -port=8081 -cc -headless
Starting application setup (label=default, base_dir=).
[0.000257] TID=0: Loading configuration from /root/.gdfuse/default/config...done
Opening log file: /root/.gdfuse/default/gdfuse.log
Clearing cache...done
Please, open the following URL in a web browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8081%2Foauth2callback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force
Please enter the verification code: 

Then in the browser you will open a URL. This is because by default when you configure your Client ID, loopback IP addres is used.
From URL copy the 'code' parameter.  Plug that in.
Note: Does not matter that 127.0.0.1 is not reachable. Page result will be not found, but URL still correct.
Please enter the verification code: ZZZZ
Access token retrieved correctly.

Then run
google-drive-ocamlfuse -debug /content/drive/

(drive folder is empty)
From Terminal you can see your files now.
/content# ls -lh drive/
total 681K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 681K Nov 15  2019 'Getting started'
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  149 May 31  2021 'Interview Notes.desktop'

